# specify two elements with one target selector

Tags: css, html, target

Hi I am trying to have a link change two element styles at once. But I am not sure how the syntax would be in that case.

I have seen something like this work;

```
#header:target #buttons-container a.open-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
```

How I read this is, it starts with the selector anchor from the link used in the HTML and then you specify the path of the selector and end with the style within the bracelets.

I got this working but now I would like that same anchor/link to target an other element at the same time. So two elements at the same time. The show-menu button changes into close-menu and the navigation div shows or hides.

How would the syntax be?

I am trying to make a pure css show and hide menu button in the header div wich targets its own style and the navigation div's style.

Here is the code;

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
}
/* Hide Menu*/
#mainmenu{
    display: none;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}

/* Display Menu Items */
#header:target #mainmenu{
    display: block;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;

}
/* Hide Open Toggle Link */
#header:target #buttons-container a.open-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
/* Show Close Toggle Link */
#header:target #buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

The HTML code

```
<div class="header-div" id="header">
<div id="buttons-container" >
            <a href="#header" class="open-menu-primary"><span>menu</a>
            <a href="#" class="close-menu-primary"><span>close</span></a>
</div>
</div>
  <nav class="navigation" id="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu" id="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">main1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">main2</a>
      <ul id="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub2/a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">main3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I target the element that contains both the targets I wanted to target.
CSS code:

```
.wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
}
#buttons-container {
    background-color: #006cad;
    text-align:right;
    padding:16px;
}
/* Hide Menu*/
#mainmenu{
    display: none;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
/* Display Menu Items */
#wrap:target .navigation #mainmenu{
    display: block;
}
#buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: none;

}
/* Hide Open Toggle Link */
#wrap:target #buttons-container a.open-menu-primary{
    display: none;
}
/* Show Close Toggle Link */
#wrap:target #buttons-container a.close-menu-primary{
    display: block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="header" id="header">
<div id="buttons-container" >
                <a href="#wrap" class="open-menu-primary"><span>menu</a>
                <a href="#" class="close-menu-primary"><span>close</span></a>
</div>
</div>
      <nav class="navigation" id="navigation">
      <ul class="mainmenu" id="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="">main1</a></li>
        <li id="hover-sub"><a href="javascript:void(0)">main2</a>
          <ul id="submenu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" class="con">main3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is a Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SanMoll/k8ej4fmo/10/)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for a comma delimited list of selectors. If I wanted to hide all h1's and all spans I could write

```
h1, span {
      display: none;
}
```

Or at least a part of your example

```
 /* Hide Menu*/
 #mainmenu, #buttons-container a.close-menu-primary {         
      display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much, but that doesn't work with the target selector. But I found the solution in a other way. I had to target a wrapper div that contains both the element then I can specify the path after the target selector to the elements needed.

Comment: Hmm, maybe in missing the point then. Space delimited shows hierarchy, to select multiple child elements from the target at the same level, wouldn't it be #wrap:target a, #wrap:target div ?

Comment: You are right in case they have the same styling so I can wrap the toggle close menu together with the show navigation styling indeed.

Comment: My problem in the first place was targeting two different elements, now that I put the two div's in one containing div I can target them with the same link in the HTML, that is where I link/target 2 styles together in a way.

Comment: I mean in the HTML is where I target two elements at the same time and in the CSS I style them saperatly.